# how to rotation using touch in MapBox swift3 sdk

Tags: swift3

@IBAction func handlePan(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

```
let t = sender.location(in: self.view)
    let x = t.x
    let y = t.y
 print(x,y)
```

}

the x and y position is same if bottom or top to left and right then. I dont know how to identify the position while swiping.

Please given suggestion regarding this issue.